# Recurring job is triggered on several workers at the same time

Tags: c#, concurrency, hangfire

I am using the latest stable hangfire (1.6.17.0).

I have 4-6 workers running in parallel at all times.

When new workers start up, they are verifying that all jobs are well created - and adding/updating all the jobs that should run, using the following code:

```
var jobId = HangfireConsts.FormatReccurringJobStore(storeId); 

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    jobId,
    () => ExecuteRefreshStore(storeId),
    Cron.HourInterval(8),
    null,
    HangfireConsts.QueueStores);
```

I figured this should be harmless since I'm using AddOrUpdate() - so worst case it should just update the existing. The locking system would make sure each of the jobs is added once (based on the jobId). This allows me to start even of a fresh new clean schema for the scheduler, and get persistent results - as all recurring jobs will be re-created.

Yet, I can see that some of the jobs start, with the exact same jobId, are triggered at the exact same time on multiple workers. Sometimes on 2 workers in parallel, sometimes on 3 workers in parallel, sometimes on 4 or 5 (out of 6).

How is that possible? Is this a bug?

**Worker 1**
[image: Worker 1]

**Worker 2**
[image: Worker 2]

**Worker 3**
[image: Worker 3]

Answer (score 3):

The following is based on comments from [Performing recurrent tasks](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html) documentation:

- One approach is to not create a scheduled job but to create single shot delayed job which creates a new delayed job when it is finished processing.

  The main problem with this is that if you start two processors, you now have to decide which one of them schedules the first job.
- Another one is to use the `[DisableConcurrentExecution]` attribute with 0 timeout on the job method together with `AutomaticRetry` to avoid retries (and warn logs):

  ```
  [DisableConcurrentExecution(0)]
  [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0, LogEvents = false, OnAttemptsExceeded = AttemptsExceededAction.Delete)]
  ```

Comment: Thank you. Rescheduling a job when it finishes is a good idea, but contradicts the Hangfire common way of recurring jobs.

The problem with `[DisableConcurrentExecution]` is that it doesn't take the parameters into account. I have thousands of jobs running, and they can run in parallel, as long as the parameter is unique.

Comment: @TheRennen Did you ever get a solution for this?  Amazed there's no easy way to stop recurring jobs with different params from colliding.

Comment: No. Was frustrated and moved away from this product.

Answer (score 0):

Hey we had this same issue and found out someone had made changes to our Cron Expressions to try to add sub minute crons which caused the above issue for us.

BAD:

```
 public static CronExpression Minutely()
        {
            return new CronExpression("* * * * * *");
        }

    public static CronExpression Hourly(int minute)
        {
            return new CronExpression($"* {minute} * * * *");
        }
```

GOOD:

```
 public static CronExpression Minutely()
        {
            return new CronExpression("* * * * *");
        }

 public static CronExpression Hourly(int minute)
        {
            return new CronExpression($"{minute} * * * *");
        }
```